# Android 2.3.4 - Http Live Streaming

Tags: java, android, http-live-streaming

I'm working on this project for a client and we're supposed to stream audio from a server onto a device running Android Gingerbread.  To retrieve the stream, the Android client needs to make a request for a variant playlist, and then make a request for the playlist itself (the one with URIs that point to the TS file chunks themselves).  Once that's done, the client app decrypts the chunks and sends them to the platform for playback.

The problem I'm having revolves around the security part.  Our client(the company in question) uses a proprietary encryption scheme that serves the keys for decrypting the TS file chunks ahead of time through an HTTP request instead of following the HLS spec and serving the key files through URI(s) listed in the index files themselves. As far as I can tell, the Android Mediaplayer framework has the ability to find these key files and generate/find the appropriate IVs for decryption IF the key file URIs are in the index files.

Unfortunately, what this all means is that I can't decrypt the file chunks and play back the stream without gaps between each segment -- I accomplish this by making HTTP GET requests for each segment, downloading them to internal storage, applying decrypting, and then playing them back using the following code:

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    File dir = new File(TS_FILE_DIR);
    String [] files = dir.list();

    mTsFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
    for (String file : files) {
        String path = TS_FILE_DIR + file;
        mTsFiles.add(new File(path));
    }

    mMediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_view_1);

    mVideoView.setVideoPath(mTsFiles.get(0).getAbsolutePath());
    mVideoView.setMediaController(mMediaController);
    mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mp.start();
        }
    });
    mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.pause();
            mp.reset();

            if (mIndex < mTsFiles.size()) {
                mIndex++;

                try {
                    mp.setDataSource(mTsFiles.get(mIndex).getAbsolutePath());
                    mp.prepareAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    });
}
```

I've tried:

1) Using 2 mediaplayers and switching between the 2, but it doesn't work at all
2) Staring at the source code for ICS to get an idea of how this all works, but its very complex and I'm not well versed in c++

Is there anything I missed?

Comment: is buffer the thing here? I have almost a similar issue and we had a circular buffer which had the capability to decode the content and send it. I am not sure if that will align with your issue.